# Postgresql group by error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table,

[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJlAT.png)

I need to group them by address with 2 different rate 5 ride IDs and 2 different rate 1 ride IDs. The problem is I already tried so may ways but it always give me these type of errors in sql:

```
More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Below is my query:

```
SELECT 
    e1.ride_id,  
    e1.rate,  
    concat(e1.service_date, ' ', e1.service_start) AS e1_timestamp_service_start,  
    concat(e1.service_date, ' ', e1.service_end) AS e1_timestamp_service_end,

    e1.fare,  
    e1.trip_total_amount,  
    e1.actual_mileage,  
    e1.calc_mileage,  
    (SELECT e1.booked_pickup FROM efleet e1 GROUP BY e1.booked_pickup) as e1_booked_pickup,  
    e1.booked_dropoff,

    e2.ride_id,  
    e2.rate,  
    concat(e2.service_date, ' ', e2.service_start) AS e2_timestamp_service_start,  
    concat(e2.service_date, ' ', e2.service_end) AS e2_timestamp_service_end,

    e2.fare,  
    e2.trip_total_amount,  
    e2.actual_mileage,  
    e2.calc_mileage,  
    e2.booked_pickup,  
    e2.booked_dropoff,

    e2.trip_total_amount - e1.trip_total_amount AS total_amount_difference,  
    e2.actual_mileage - e1.actual_mileage AS actual_mileage_difference

FROM efleet e1, efleet e2

WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM e1.service_date) = 11
  AND e2.service_date BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-11-30'
  AND e1.rate = '5'
  AND e2.rate = '1' 
  AND e1.booked_trip_start_long = e2.booked_trip_start_long
  AND e1.booked_trip_start_lat = e2.booked_trip_start_lat
  AND e1.booked_trip_end_long = e2.booked_trip_end_long
  AND e1.booked_trip_end_lat = e2.booked_trip_end_lat
  AND e1.status = 'Approved'
  AND e2.status = 'Approved'
  AND e1.service_date = e2.service_date
  AND e2.service_start BETWEEN (e1.service_start - '01:00:00') AND (e1.service_start + '01:00:00')

ORDER BY e1_booked_pickup;
```

Comment: `(SELECT e1.booked_pickup FROM efleet e1 GROUP BY e1.booked_pickup)` is apparently returning more than one row.  Fix it so that it only returns one row.

Comment: Also, the fact that you're using `e1` as an identifier in both your main query and your subquery is a bit suspect.

Comment: How can i do that? Is there any other way to group/limit that column without affecting other columns?

Comment: What about something like `(SELECT first(booked_pickup) FROM efleet GROUP BY booked_pickup)` or `(SELECT TOP 1 booked_pickup FROM efleet)`

Comment: it appears to be postgresql doesn't recognize the first function, i tried limit and top clause but it gives me another error

Comment: Well, that's your mandate.  Whatever that subquery is, it must return only one row and one column.

Comment: when i group them by e1.booked_pickup without a subquery it gives me this "ERROR:  column "e1.ride_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT e1.ride_id, e1.rate, concat(e1.service_date, ' ', e1...." is there a way i can group them by 2 without affecting ride id and rate column?\

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew what that subquery was trying to accomplish.  Maybe you could get by with a join instead.

Comment: im trying to group them by addresses, in every address there should be 2 unique ride ID for rate 5 and same thing with rate 1. basically it almost like a left join based on my selection of fields. the only thing that is pulling me back is that this condition is giving me too much unique data on other columns that's why SQL doesn't allow me to group them. If there is a way i can randomly group data from those other column, it would be very helpful.

Comment: i updated the image so that everybody can see a better view on my data.

Comment: @jpabiado share sample data and expected output will get your best answer.. Rather than fixing your query.. Not as image formatted.. Use this https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: i cannot post the data because the output in the ASCII table is too long even if i truncate the fields still it gives me too much. where can i possibly show you that? @dwir182

Comment: @jpabiado why don't just call `e1.booked_pickup` rather use subquery? you can use this https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: @dwir182 it should be in group of at least 2 different unique rate 5 rideIDs and rate 1 rideIDs. that's why it is a problem

Comment: I could not say more without sample data and your expected output..

Comment: If some output is too wide, use psql's \x command. If you want to use several results from your subquery where only one row is allowed, use some aggregating function like array_agg() or string_agg(), which combine several values into one.